# Load PHP File On Div Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to load a php file on a div element but let the div content there. example

```
$('.Load_Div').load('example.php');
```

and lets say on Load_Div i have a content what i don't want to be removed and the load page to be on the end of content example example.php = [Loaded PHP]

```
<div class="Load_Div">Here is Loading PHP: [Loaded PHP]</div>
```

so "Here is Loading PHP:" to remain there all time when the example.php is loaded

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways of doing this but the easiest is just to add a container div for your loaded content:

```
<div>Here is Loading PHP: <div class="Load_Div"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm maybe, you can do something as simple as adding another div, if you want to do it dinamically it would be something like:

```
$('.Load_Div').append('<div id="heyImYourNewDiv"></div>');
$('#heyImYourNewDiv').load('example.php');
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have two choice:

```
<div>
   <div class="prev-content">Here is Loading PHP:</div>
   <div class="Load_Div"> [Loaded PHP]</div>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div>
   Here is Loading PHP:
   <div class="Load_Div"> [Loaded PHP]</div>
</div>
```

and then

```
$('.Load_Div').load('example.php');
```

Comment: What this is loading page using jquery only

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var content = $('.Load_Div').html();
$('.Load_Div').load('example.php');
$('.Load_Div').text(content.concat($('.Load_Div').html()));
```

EDIT:

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var content = $('.Load_Div').html();
        $('.Load_Div').load('example.php', function () {
            $('.Load_Div').html(content.concat($('.Load_Div').html()));
        });
    });
```

It's working for me

Comment: $('.Load_Div').text(content.concat($('.Load_Div').html())); this command give me error and is not working ...

Comment: @MihaiViteazu: Did you try it? Did it work OR is there any problem?